# Vue.js not detecting data change with push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have this method that sets a data structuce in my `attributes` object.

```
setAttributes(data) {
  const attr = data.attributes;

  attr.forEach(attribute => {
    attribute.attributes.forEach(item => {
      if (!this.attributes[attribute.name]) {
        this.$set(this.attributes, attribute.name, {
          name: attribute.name,
          attributes: []
        });
      }

      if (!this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes[item.id]) {
        this.$set(this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes, item.id, {
          name: item.name.value,
          attributes: []
        });
      }

      this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes[item.id].attributes.push(item);
    });
  });
}
```

Everything works except the last line `this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes[item.id].attributes.push(item);` where Vue doesn't detect the data change and the array is still empty.

As I am aware, `push()` should make Vue detect a data change or is that not true?

Comment: do you mean that vue doesn't detect that there is some changes in attributes and should re-render ?

Comment: @SaJed `this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes[item.id].attributes` of each item is still an empty array, after this method is run on all data - that's basically the problem :)

Comment: And if I console log `this.attributes[attribute.name].attributes[item.id].attributes`, I can see that the items get pushed to the array, but Vue doesn't seem to detect that.

Comment: You are right Vue should be able to detect changes. Can you please make a simplified example in an online editor in order to help you?

Comment: @KrisD.J.taking a look now

Comment: @roliroli I have posted an answer with the solution, thanks for the help though, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this code:

```
setAttributes(data) {
  const attr = data.attributes;

  attr.forEach(attribute => {
    const name = attribute.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/[^a-z0-9 -]/g, '')
      .replace(/\s+/g, '_');

    if (!this.attributes[name]) {
      this.$set(this.attributes, name, {
        name: attribute.name,
        attributes: {}
      });
    }

    attribute.attributes.forEach(item => {
      if (!this.attributes[name].attributes[item.id]) {
        this.$set(this.attributes[name].attributes, item.id, {
          name: item.name.value,
          attributes: []
        });
      }

      this.attributes[name].attributes[item.id].attributes.push(item);
    });
  });
}
```

The problem was that `attributes` was set as an array and not an object in the first if statement.